# typeof Equivalent for Object Types in PL/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I'm trying to use OOP and TDD inside of Oracle.  Yes, I know that sounds crazy.  And, I need some advice.

I'm writing a test for the following constructor method (simplified for the purposes of this question):

```
CONSTRUCTOR FUNCTION PERSON(p_pidm NUMBER, p_throw_exception NUMBER DEFAULT 0, p_program_id NUMBER DEFAULT 0)
RETURN SELF AS RESULT IS

BEGIN

    -- Attach constructor parameters to internal attributes
    self.throw_exception := p_throw_exception;
    self.program_id := p_program_id;

    -- TESTING STUDENT INSTANTIATION
    self.student := NEW STUDENT(self.a_pidm);

    RETURN;
END;
```

In the corresponding test, I'll need to verify that `self.student` is set to a valid instance of `STUDENT`.  In other languages, I do this with a typeof method, but I'm not aware of one in PL/SQL.

So, the question is, does anyone know a function/procedure that I can pass a user-defined type into and get back its class/type name?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably want to use the [`IS OF <<type>>` syntax](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14260/adobjbas.htm#sthref381).

Something like

```
IF l_variable IS OF( student )
THEN
  <<do something>>
END IF;
```

Comment: /#justin This is perfect.  Thank you.